# Monitor Disk Usage per directory/file

Tags: monitoring, disk-usage

I have a huge java app that drives my disk crazy. As I think that this issue is only due to 3-5 small things I would like to monitor what is written to/read from disk within an hour sorted by size and actions.

Is there any app that runs under ubuntu 1204 that could help me with this issue and give me an average report after an hour of profiling or so?

Or would you handle the whole issue differently?

Answer (score 1):

You could turn to ncdu which is a good tool to monitor the disk.
http://www.heitorlessa.com/ncdu-different-way-to-obtain-disk-usage-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

1.Make or reuse some script for monitoring disk usage, you can easily write based on df command : `df -h <disk> grep -v Filesystem |awk '{print $5}'`  this is just starting point.

2.Make some tresholds in script e.g if used is 80 % make output WARNING, if used is 90 % make output CRITICAL, so as you can see this is perfect place to use Nagios or some other monitoring tool with graphing usage so you can easily monitor per hour day, month, year. Laziest and best solution from my point of view

3.If you want custom solution, i will use cron for this, so i will make script with my tresholds and put it in cron to be exectued every hour,

```
crontab -e

* 0 * * * /path/to/script >> /some/file
```

This can be sent via email (if you have working MTA agent on machine) or script can generate some CSV report or simply make output of the script to be apended to some file with timestamps.